# why do i keep getting an error 404 when fetching images from a backend folder in webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would appreciate if someone knows the answer!!
I am defining the image src from the backend using an object key for my image.Maybe this is the problem because i think i have imported properly and used the file loader in webpack.config.js
index.js

```
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen.js";
import Error404Screen from "./screens/Error404Screen.js";
import { parseRequestUrl } from "./utils.js";
import '../styles/style.css';
import myImage from './images/product-1.jpg';

const routes = {
    "/":HomeScreen,
    "/product/:id":ProductScreen,
}
const router = async () => {
    const request = parseRequestUrl();
    const parseUrl = 
    (request.resource ? `/${request.resource}` : '/' ) + 
    (request.id ? '/:id' : '') + 
    (request.verb ? `/${request.verb}` : '');
    const screen = routes[parseUrl] ? routes[parseUrl] : Error404Screen;
    
    const main = document.getElementById('main-container');
    
    main.innerHTML = await screen.render();
};;


window.addEventListener('load',router);
window.addEventListener('hashchange',router);
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const fileLoaderPlugin = require('file-loader');
const { truncate } = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    mode:'development',
    target:'web',
    entry:{
       main : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    },
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'frontend'),
        filename:'[name][content.hash].js',
        assetModuleFilename:'[name]'
    },
    devServer:{
       static:{
    },
        port:3000,
        open:true,
        hot:true,
        compress:true,
        historyApiFallback:true,
       
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css$/, 
                use:
                ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader',],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
                 },
                
                use: [
                  'file-loader',
                  {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                      bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
                      disable: true,
                      esModule: false, // webpack@2.x and newer
                    },
                  },
                ],
              }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title:'Webpack App',
            filename:'index.html',
            template:'frontend/index.html',
        }),
        new fileLoaderPlugin({
            
        }),
    ]
    
}
```

HomeScreen.js that use on render method

```
const HomeScreen = {
    render:async () => {
        // const { products } = data;
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/products",{
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            },
        });
        if(!response || !response.ok){
            return `<div>Error in getting data</div>`;
        }

        const products = await response.json();
        return `
    <ul class = 'products'>
         ${products.map(product => `
      <li>
        <div class="product">
         <a href="/#/product/1">
             <img src="require${product.image}" alt="${product.name}" />
         </a>
         <div class="product-name">
             <a href="/#/product/${product._id}">
                 ${product.name}
             </a>
         </div>
         <div class="product-brand">
             ${product.brand}
         </div>
         <div class="product-price">
             ${product.price} €
         </div>
        </div>
      </li>
         `).join('\n')}
    </ul>

        `
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: that would suggest your path(s) are incorrect

Comment: Thank you very much because im quite new on this .Do you mean the path on import or in src ?

Comment: whatever is giving you the 404 error, probably the image src if that's what you say you get 404 errors on - we can't see where your images are in relation to the root of the http server, so, not possible to tell you what you're doing wrong, just that you are doing it wrong